# Bash command to recursively list files but sorting by classification

Tags: bash, sorting, find

I often use the excellent [find](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html) program in Bash to list files with certain filters. For example, in a Subversion (SVN) working copy, I sometimes wish to recursively list all files but excluding the `.svn` subdirectories as follows:

```
find . -name '.svn' -prune -o -type f -print
```

Today, I wanted to do something similar, but I also wanted to affect the order in which directory contents were listed: I wanted 'ordinary' files to be followed by sub-directories (and then the recursive contents). There does not appear to be an option for this.

The [ls](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/ls-invocation.html) (list) command has an option to list recursively. This command has many sorting options, including list by file name, access time, size, and so on, but not classification, although the `-p` option will annotate directories.

Now, I *could* write, e.g., a Python script to do exactly what I want. However, `find` already does almost everything I want. Usually within a Bash shell, it is possible to combine programs to do just what you want: each program, like `find`, `sort`, `uniq`, `ls`, `wc`, performs a simple task, but does so well. Not every program needs to be able to sort because `sort` can sort. So, really, I'm just curious...

**My question is, do you know if there's a way to do what I want: to both filter and sort a recursive file listing, just by combining Bash programs?**

For example, `find` gives me the files in this, alphabetical, order:

```
a.txt
b\file1.txt
b\subdir\file2.txt
b\then_file3.txt
c.txt
d\file4.txt
e.txt
```

but I'd prefer them in this order, where within each directory, the ordinary files are listed alphabetically first, followed by the directories, again alphabetically:

```
a.txt
c.txt
e.txt
b\file1.txt
b\then_file3.txt
b\subdir\file2.txt
d\file4.txt
```

(I am a Windows user, but I run a Bash shell in [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).)

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use an embedded find.  The outer find locates all directories and executes an inner find which shows just the files you want in that directory:

```
find . -type d -exec find {} -type f -maxdepth 1 \;
```

Comment: This works, but issues warnings.  They may be turned off by `-nowarn` option.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would probably be possible somehow.

So, my SVN filtering example would be

    find . -name '.svn' -prune -o -type d -exec find {} -type f -nowarn -maxdepth 1 \;

Comment: When I try this, the result is unsorted (by dir and within dir levels).

Answer (score 4):

This groups the directories within each level first, then the files and recurses into each level and does the same:

```
ls -lR --group-directories-first
```

It's upside down from what you wanted, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
tree -fi
```

On Ubuntu and CentOS (and Red Hat, Fedora...) it's contained in its own package, called "tree" (duh). Ubuntu doesn't seem to install that package by default, the others do.

EDIT: Sorry, didn't realize you're using Cygwin. Well, it's ported to Cygwin too. If it's not in the default set, [see here](http://freshmeat.net/projects/tree/).

Comment: You can add a `-a` to get the hidden files, too.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state how you wanted to handle things if the directories go more than one level deep.  Does something like this do what you're looking for?  It does a breadth-first listing, sorted within each depth level:

```
$for ((l = 0; l <= 24; l++)); do find . -mindepth ${l} -maxdepth ${l} -type f | sort; done
```

Comment: That was difficult to express, so I tried to illustrate that in the example. I *don't* want all files, and then all directories (that's easy).

Whilst at a given directory, I want first to list the files, and then to process each subdirectory, recursing into each in turn.